# How to use Rank() in BigQuery and restart Rank counting by timeframe?

Tags: google-bigquery, ranking

In BigQuery, I'm wanting to create a ranked list by SKU sales per Season, however I'm getting a bit lost with how to do this with the current state of my code. My desired output is something like:

```
Season      | SKU         | total_spent | Rank 
Spring 2020 | SKU_sample1 | $200 | 1
Spring 2020 | SKU_sample2 | $190 | 2
Spring 2020 | SKU_sample3 | $185 | 3
```

--- so forth, then restart the ranking when the Season changes

```
Season      | SKU         | total_spent | Rank 
Halloween 2020 | SKU_sample1 | $500 | 1
Halloween 2020 | SKU_sample2 | $400 | 2
Halloween 2020 | SKU_sample3 | $300 | 3
```

My base code is this:

```
SELECT DATE(sales_time) as sales_time,
    CASE
        WHEN DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-04-09' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-04-23' THEN 'Spring 2020'
        WHEN DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-10-29' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-11-02' THEN 'Halloween 2020'
        WHEN DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-11-25' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-12-03' THEN 'Thanksgiving 2020'
        WHEN DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-12-17' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2021-01-04' THEN 'Xmas 2020'
      ELSE
      'unknown_season'
    END
      AS season,
    sku,
    SUM(salesPrice) as total_spent
    FROM sales_table
    WHERE
       DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-04-09' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-04-23' 
        OR (DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-10-29' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-11-02')
        OR (DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-11-25' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2020-12-03')
        OR (DATE(sales_time) >= '2020-12-17' AND DATE(sales_time) <= '2021-01-04')
    GROUP BY  sku,
    DATE(sales_time),
    salesPrice,
    season
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've broken it down a bit using CTEs to encapsulate the ranking logic:

```
with data as (
    select
        sku,
        case
            when date(sales_time) between '2020-04-09' and '2020-04-23' then 'Spring 2020'
            when date(sales_time) between '2020-10-29' and '2020-11-02' then 'Halloween 2020'
            when date(sales_time) between '2020-11-25' and '2020-12-03' then 'Thanksgiving 2020'
            when date(sales_time) between '2020-12-17' and '2021-01-04' then 'Xmas 2020'
            else 'unknown_season'
        end as season,
        sum(salesPrice) as total_spent
    from `project.dataset.sales_table`
    where
        (
            date(sales_time) between '2020-04-09' and '2020-04-23' or
            date(sales_time) between '2020-10-29' and '2020-11-02' or
            date(sales_time) between '2020-11-25' and '2020-12-03' or
            date(sales_time) between '2020-12-17' and '2021-01-04'
        )
        group by 1,2
),
ranked as (
    select 
        season, 
        sku, 
        total_spent,
        -- Within each season, rank by total_spent -- could also use row_number() if you want to break ties
        rank() over(partition by season order by total_spent desc) as spend_rank
    from data
)
select * from ranked
order by season, spend_rank asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below option

```
#standardSQL
select season, sku, total_spent, 
  rank() over(partition by season order by total_spent desc) as `rank`
from (
  select min(date(sales_time)) season_start, sku, sum(salesPrice) as total_spent, 
    case 
      when date(sales_time) between '2020-04-09' and '2020-04-23' then 'Spring 2020'
      when date(sales_time) between '2020-10-29' and '2020-11-02' then 'Halloween 2020'
      when date(sales_time) between '2020-11-25' and '2020-12-03' then 'Thanksgiving 2020'
      when date(sales_time) between '2020-12-17' and '2021-01-04' then 'Xmas 2020'
      else 'unknown_season' 
    end as season  
  from `project.dataset.sales_table`
  group by season, sku
)
order by season_start, `rank`
```

with output like below

[image]